# Returns unexpected value

Tags: python, if-statement, try-except

I wrote this code for an online course I am taking and you cant post code and get specific help there. I hope that someone here will help. 
Code -

```
largest = None
smallest = None
numI = 0
while True:
    num = raw_input("Prompt you")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        numI = int(num)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue
    if numI >= largest or numI < smallest:
        if numI > largest:
            largest = numI
        else:
            smallest = numI 

print "Maximum is",largest
print "Minimum is",smallest
```

Why does it return "Minimum is None"?
I tried with two If loops, an If and and Elif, and now this nested loop. No matter what I dont seem to reach setting of the minimum value.

Any help greatly appreciated.

(Code is turned in and rated, so you cant ruin that part :) )

Comment: `smallest` starts out as `None` and only changes if `numI < smallest`.  When will `numI < None` be true?

Comment: In Python 2.7 `0 > None == True` and `0 < None == False`. In Python 3.x this would have thrown an error about comparing unorderable types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x < None will always return false, so in your `While True:` statement you need to add

```
if largest==None:
    largest=numI
if smallest==None:
    smallest=numI
```

code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
numI = 0
while True:
    num = raw_input("Prompt you")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        numI = int(num)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue
    if largest==None:
        largest=numI
    if smallest==None:
        smallest=numI
    if numI > largest or numI < smallest:
        if numI > largest:
            largest = numI
        else:
            smallest = numI 

print "Maximum is",largest
print "Minimum is",smallest
```

Note using `print('Maximum is ' + str(largest))` is good practice since it is cross compatible with 3.4

Comment: Note that there's a subtle bug in this code carried over from OP's original, which is every time a value comes along that is equal to `largest` but not greater, it will incorrectly set that as the `smallest` instead. Separating the conditions instead gets around that.

Comment: @user2800105 if you like the answer you can accept it

Answer (score 1):

In python 2, `None` is less than everything. So your `numI < smallest` condition will NEVER pass. You should explicitly test for None instead so that `numI` gets set to the first value in the initial pass, then it can update as normal.

Also, you should just use two independent checks:

```
if largest is None or numI > largest:
    largest = numI
if smallest is None or numI < smallest:
    smallest = numI
```